# NGINX: How to allow full access if a certain HTTP header is set, else trigger HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: nginx, http-headers

As the question implies I want to allow full access to my website if the `X-Auth` HTTP header is set and contains a specific string. If this is not the case, HTTP basic authentication should be triggered. Something like this:

```
if ($http_x_auth = "some_string") {
  allow access;
} else {
  auth_basic "Authentication";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/security_http_basic_auth_file;
}
```

Unfortunately NGINX does not allow if else statements. Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: `if-else` is useless in this case, juste invert your condition and request basic auth if the header doesn't match the string.

Comment: @Ginnungagap Thanks, but you can not use any basic auth statements within the NGINX if statement, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Manifestor were you able to take a look at my solution using "map" below?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

In the `http` block:

```
map $http_x_auth $has_basic_auth {
    "some_string" no_basic_auth;
    default with_basic_auth;
}
```

In your `location` block:

```
try_files nonexistent @$has_basic_auth;
```

And then add two named `location`s:

```
location @no_basic_auth {
    # insert your config
}
location @with_basic_auth {
    # insert your config with basic auth
}
```

Comment: @manifestor were you able to resolve your issue with this?